# Separator lines for custom spinner are not displayed in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, baseadapter

I am using a custom BaseAdapter to create a custom spinner where I am using

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) {
    return cnvtView;
}
```

to display a drop down bar. But between the text items here the separator lines are displayed in android 5. This happens only for lollipop version. Not sure why is this happening.

Also tried using

```
 @Override
 public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return true;
 }

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}
```

Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Material guidelines state that menus aren't supposed to have dividers unless you are separating sections of items. I believe this defaults for the views 5.0+. You can see more info here: http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-usage

Comment: So what you are saying is it is not supported by default? But I could see in few apps they are appearimg, not sure how is that? Added explicitly?